# Python 3.x, Trouble accessing key value with special characters in Python Dict (loaded through json)

Tags: json, xml, python-3.x, unicode, elementtree

I am looking for help accessing key values with special characters (accented letters and such) in Python 3.x dictionary formats. So here's what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a `.xml` file that I parse into Python with ElementTree:

```
...
    tree = ElementTree.parse(fileNamePath)
...
```

The source is a program called Cockatrice. It is their card.xml file.

I have a `.json` text file that I load with `json.load(open(fileName))`.

The source is: https://mtgjson.com/json/AllCards-x.json.zip

Both databases contain over 16,000 entries and are too cumbersome for me to easily print out at once on the oldPC I must use. Plus, with some of the special characters, `CMD` isn't always willing to print them.

Anyway...

I am using the names found in the XML file as the variable to use when searching the JSON (converted to DICT) keys.

```
cardName=root[1][loop_control01].find('name').text
```

I then pull the info I want from the JSON/DICT with that name and mostly it works well with the exception of when it gets to a name with special characters. An example that keeps popping up is `Bösium Strip`.

The Error Message is a Key error:

```
KeyError: 'Bösium Strip'
```

I have confirmed that the key exists in the JSON by looking through it manually through notepad. In the XML file the text is spelled as:

```
...
  <card>
     <name>Bösium Strip</name>...
```

and in the JSON file it is spelled as:

```
...
    "Bösium Strip":{
        "layout":"normal",...
```

While I do know of the problems printing these characters out in CMD, that does not seem to be the issue here as I am not printing them to screen. I just need to be able to reference the key in searching the JSON/DICT.

I have tried several of the answers found here on StackOverflow to no avail. I either need to search the JSON/DICT using the same format/encoding of characters or I need to iterate through the JSON/DICT and reformat all the keys to a more easily searchable format/encoding.

Any help accomplishing either would make me happy. Thanks to anyone who takes the time to give me a nice solution-present for my birthday today <3

Comment: Solid question, I have to say! And congratulations :)

Comment: @m0m0e Happy Birthday !

Comment: Thanks so much! <3 You guys gave me an awesome present of an updated cockatrice cards.xml that has the card legalities per format. Will share with all when it's public-ready. Thank you all so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where your problem is, the following works on python 3.4.2

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

jsonstring = """
[{
    "Bösium Strip": {
        "layout": "normal"
    },
    "test": {
        "hello1": "hello2"
    }
}]
"""
#data is a now a single element list, element containing dictionary
data = json.loads(jsonstring)

#both the following works
print(data[0].get('test', ''))
print(data[0].get('Bösium Strip', ''))

#the following works as well
keys = list(data[0].keys())
for key in keys:
    print(key)
    print(data[0].get(key))
```

However this example is using `json.loads()` not `json.load()` the later will take a file object, you may have to experiment with the encoding of that object, example:

```
json.load(open(filename, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8'))
```

I just checked some of my own code, and I do it this way:

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding = e) as openfileobject:
    data = openfileobject.read()
    data = _check_json_data(data)  #this is my own check
    data = json.loads(data)
```

Where I can set the `e` to the correct encoding of the file, and I do a check on the data to validate it is valid json to begin with (but that is for another question)

good luck!

Comment: It did end up being the json encoding that I changed on loading and it worked out, though I am willing to bet (and will investigate more) that the other response regarding normalization was the root issue. Thank you so much for the help. I used utf-8 on the json.load() and all keys seem to have found their homes. I now have a working updater for cockatrice and just need to make it public consumable.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a normalization problem.  If you `ascii()` the keys in your dictionary you can see if there is a difference between your key and the dictionary's.

For example:

```
>>> s = 'Bösium Strip'
>>> ascii(s)
"'B\\xf6sium Strip'"
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> t = ud.normalize('NFD',s)
>>> t
'Bösium Strip'
>>> s
'Bösium Strip'
>>> s==t
False
>>> ascii(s)
"'B\\xf6sium Strip'"
>>> ascii(t)
"'Bo\\u0308sium Strip'"
```

`s` uses a single Unicode character, while `t` uses a combining character with the `o`.  They display the same but don't compare the same, but you can use `unicodedata.normalize` with either `NFD` or `NFC` to convert to the decomposed or combined form.

Comment: I believe you are correct that it was a normalization issue. Evidence of this was that it could print to CMD with one key version of the fancy o but not with the other. (It could print the key from the xml file but not the json file). Thank you very much for the input. As the poster above suggested, by ensuring the json.load() encoding was set to utf-8, I was able to match all keys. Now I have an updated cockatrice cards.xml and just need to make my updater public consumable. Thanks you again